# Creating multiple dataframes using a for loop

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

Hi I have code which looks like this:

```
with open("file123.json") as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(dict([(k,pd.Series(v)) for k,v in data["spt"][1].items()]))
df_1_made =pd.json_normalize(json.loads(df_1.to_json(orient="records"))).T.drop(["content.id","shortname","name"])

df_2 = pd.DataFrame(dict([(k,pd.Series(v)) for k,v in data["spt"][2].items()]))
df_2_made = pd.json_normalize(json.loads(df_2.to_json(orient="records"))).T.drop(["content.id","shortname","name"])

df_3 = pd.DataFrame(dict([(k,pd.Series(v)) for k,v in data["spt"][3].items()]))
df_3_made = pd.json_normalize(json.loads(df_3.to_json(orient="records"))).T.drop(["content.id","shortname","name"])
```

which the dataframe is built from a json file
the problem is that I am dealing with different json files and each one of them can lead to different number of dataframes. so the code above is 3, it may change to 7. Is there any way to make a for loop taking the length of the data:

```
length = len(data["spt"])
```

and make the correct number of dataframes from it? so I do not need to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option here will be to put all your dataframes into a dictionary or a list. First define a function that creates the dataframe and then use a list comprehension.

```
def create_df(data):
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        dict(
            [(k,pd.Series(v)) for k,v in data]
        )
    )
    df =pd.json_normalize(
        json.loads(
            df.to_json(orient="records")
        )
    ).T.drop(["content.id","shortname","name"])

    return df

my_list_of_dfs = [create_df(data.items()) for x in data["spt"]]
```

Comment: The dict creation can be probably simplified to:
`{k: pd.Series(v) for k, v in data}`